# Filtering the options in a select2 ajax on the client side

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

I have implemented a Select2 component using jquery but I am not able to search and filter the results based on search term. It was working fine when I passed data directly to select2 but after I started getting the options from Ajax call, it is just underlining the selections containing the term but not filtering the results.

https://github.com/select2/select2/issues/790

It says when using ajax filtering is done on the server side but I want to filter it on the client side preferably.

Comment: Try making a request to get the JSON data ahead of time and then passing it in as `data` when initializing Select2.

Comment: The comment above is useful and should’ve been an answer to this question